# How Can Connect SSRS to Amazon Redshift Database

Tags: database, reporting-services, amazon-redshift, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I have a Redshift Database and I like to use SSRS to develop my reports. But I'm little lost with the connection

Comment: I suggest you first create a new data source. You'll see that you can create an ODBC data source. You need to install Redshift ODBC drivers on your report server and utilise that